# Polymorphism and instanceof

Tags: java, arrays, object, polymorphism, instanceof

I have programed a Worker and MachineWorker class. It complies fine. but when i run it, after three consecutive statements the program stops. I cannot find the problem, and I dont know how and when to use 'instanceof'. 
I am writing the question below and with all the classes...

Question:- (i)Declare an array that can store the references of up to 5 **Worker** or **MachineWorker** objects.
a)Allow user to enter the type of object and the data for that type of object(3 values for Worker and 4 values for MachineWorker).
b)Construct the appropriate object storing the reference in the common array.

ii)Now allow the users to enter the weekly data repeatedly. If it is **Worker** object user must enter ID and hours-worked. If it is a **MachineWorker** object user must enter ID,hoursWorked and pieces. Once these values read search through the array to locate the object with the given ID before calling the **addWeekly()**.The number of arguments either(1 or 2) to be passed to **addWeekly** depends on the type of objects being referred. To determine the type of object being referred(**Worker or MachineWorker**)you may use the **instanceof** operator.

Please see my codes below:-

```
 //Worker.java
    public class Worker { 
            public final double bonus=100;    
            protected String name, workerID;
            protected double hourlyRate, totalHoursWorked,tax,grossSalary,netSalary;

            public Worker(){

        }
    public Worker(String name, String workerID, double hourlyRate){
        this.name = name;
        this.workerID = workerID;
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;

        }

    public void addWeekly(double hoursWorked){
        this.totalHoursWorked = this.totalHoursWorked + hoursWorked;
        }

    public double gross(){
        grossSalary = (totalHoursWorked*hourlyRate);
                if(totalHoursWorked>=150){
            grossSalary = grossSalary +100;
            }
            return  grossSalary;
            }
    public double netAndTax(){
        netSalary = grossSalary;
        if(grossSalary>500){
            tax = (grossSalary - 500) *0.3;
            netSalary = (grossSalary - tax);

        }
        return netSalary;
     }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getWorkerID(){
        return this.workerID;
    }

    public double getHourlyRate(){
        return this.hourlyRate;
    }

    public double getTotalHours(){
        return totalHoursWorked;
    }

    public double getGrossSalary(){
        return grossSalary;
        }

    public void addToGross(double amt){
        grossSalary = grossSalary + amt;
    }
    public void displaySalary(){
        System.out.print("Name: " +getName() + "\nID :" + getWorkerID() 
                + "\nHourly Rate: " + getHourlyRate()+ "\nTotalHours Worked" + getTotalHours() + 
                "\nGross pay" + getGrossSalary() + "\nTax: " + netAndTax() + 
                "\nNet Pay: " + netAndTax());
    }

    }




//MachineWorker.java
    public class MachineWorker extends Worker{

        private double targetAmount;
        private double totalPieces, productivityBonus;

        public MachineWorker(String workerName, String workerID, double hourlyRate, double targetAmount)
        {
            super(workerName, workerID, hourlyRate);
            //this.productivityBonus = productivityBonus;
            this.targetAmount = targetAmount;

        }

        public void addWeekly(double hoursWorked, double weeklyAmount)
        {
            totalHoursWorked = hoursWorked + totalHoursWorked;
            totalPieces = weeklyAmount + totalPieces;
        }


        public double productivityBonus()
        {
            productivityBonus = 100 + (totalPieces - targetAmount);
            return productivityBonus;
        }

        public double gross()
        {
            grossSalary = (totalHoursWorked * hourlyRate) + productivityBonus;
            if(totalHoursWorked >= 150)
            {
                grossSalary = grossSalary + bonus;
            }
            return  grossSalary;
        }

        public void addToGross(double amt)
        {
            amt = productivityBonus;
            grossSalary = grossSalary + amt;
        }


        public void displaySalary()
        {

        System.out.println("Name    " + super.name + "\nID  " + 
        super.workerID + "\nHourly rate " + super.hourlyRate + "\nTotal Hours Worked    " + 
        super.totalHoursWorked + "\nGross Pay   $" + super.grossSalary + "\nTax $" + super.tax + "\nNetpay  $" + super.netSalary);
            System.out.println("Productivity Bonus  " + productivityBonus);
        }   
    }





  //Polymorphism PolyWorker.java

import java.util.*;
        public class PolyWorkers
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            Worker[] a = new Worker[5];
            MachineWorker[] b = new MachineWorker[5];

            char option = '0';
            String choice;
            boolean nChar = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

                System.out.print("\tType of object " + (i+1) + " [W/M]: ");
                choice = input.nextLine();

                if (choice.length() == 1)
                {
                    option = choice.charAt(0); //pick the first character

                    if (option == 'w' || option == 'W')
                    {
                        System.out.println("\n\tEnter name, ID and hours:   ");
                        String name = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("  ");
                        String id = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("  ");
                        double hours = input.nextDouble();

                        a[i] = new Worker(name, id, hours);
                        System.out.println();

                    }
                    if (option == 'm' || option == 'M')
                    {
                        System.out.print("\n\tEnter name, ID, hours and pieces: ");
                        String name = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("  ");
                        String id = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("  ");
                        double hours = input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.print("  ");
                        double pieces = input.nextDouble();

                        b[i] = new MachineWorker(name, id, hours, pieces);
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                System.out.print("\tType of object " + (i+1) + " [W/M]: ");
                choice = input.nextLine();
                }


                a[i].displaySalary();
                b[i].displaySalary();
                b[i].productivityBonus();

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have not provided the driver classes, if u need them, then I will post it, right away

Comment: A stack trace of your error would be useful.

Comment: I am new to programming. I have tried my level best for this program, but still stuck. I need professionals help or reference. It would be very helpful if my problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use overriden methods readfromInput and displaySalary to distinguish between what Worker and Machinworker does.
The different behaviour should be implemented within the classes and not in the calling Polyworker class.
If Machineworker displaySalary shows the bonus  this should be called in displaySalary of MachineWorker

see modified code below

```
//Worker.java
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * a generic worker
 */
public class Worker {
    public final double bonus = 100;
    protected String name, workerID;
    protected double hourlyRate, totalHoursWorked, tax, grossSalary, netSalary;


    public void addWeekly(double hoursWorked) {
        this.totalHoursWorked = this.totalHoursWorked + hoursWorked;
    }

    public double gross() {
        grossSalary = (totalHoursWorked * hourlyRate);
        if (totalHoursWorked >= 150) {
            grossSalary = grossSalary + 100;
        }
        return grossSalary;
    }

    public double netAndTax() {
        netSalary = grossSalary;
        if (grossSalary > 500) {
            tax = (grossSalary - 500) * 0.3;
            netSalary = (grossSalary - tax);

        }
        return netSalary;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getWorkerID() {
        return this.workerID;
    }

    public double getHourlyRate() {
        return this.hourlyRate;
    }

    public double getTotalHours() {
        return totalHoursWorked;
    }

    public double getGrossSalary() {
        return grossSalary;
    }

    public void addToGross(double amt) {
        grossSalary = grossSalary + amt;
    }

    public void displaySalary() {
        System.out.print("Name: " + getName() + "\nID :" + getWorkerID()
                + "\nHourly Rate: " + getHourlyRate() + "\nTotalHours Worked"
                + getTotalHours() + "\nGross pay" + getGrossSalary() + "\nTax: "
                + netAndTax() + "\nNet Pay: " + netAndTax());
    }

    public void readFromInput(Scanner input) {
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("  ");
        this.workerID= input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("  ");
        this.totalHoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();
    }

} // Worker

//MachineWorker.java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MachineWorker extends Worker {

    private double targetAmount;
    private double totalPieces, productivityBonus;

    public void addWeekly(double hoursWorked, double weeklyAmount) {
        totalHoursWorked = hoursWorked + totalHoursWorked;
        totalPieces = weeklyAmount + totalPieces;
    }

    public double productivityBonus() {
        productivityBonus = 100 + (totalPieces - targetAmount);
        return productivityBonus;
    }

    public double gross() {
        grossSalary = (totalHoursWorked * hourlyRate) + productivityBonus;
        if (totalHoursWorked >= 150) {
            grossSalary = grossSalary + bonus;
        }
        return grossSalary;
    }

    public void addToGross(double amt) {
        amt = productivityBonus;
        grossSalary = grossSalary + amt;
    }

    @Override
    public void displaySalary() {
        super.displaySalary();
        System.out.println("Productivity Bonus  " + productivityBonus);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFromInput(Scanner input) {
        super.readFromInput(input);
        this.totalPieces = input.nextDouble();
    }
}

//Polymorphism PolyWorker.java

import java.util.*;

public class PolyWorkers {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Worker[] workers = new Worker[5];

        char option = '0';
        String choice;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            System.out.print("\tType of object " + (i + 1) + " [W/M]: ");
            choice = input.nextLine();

            if (choice.length() == 1) {
                option = choice.toLowerCase().charAt(0); // pick the first character
                switch (option) {
                case 'w': {
                    workers[i] = new Worker();
                    System.out.println("\n\tEnter name, ID and hours:   ");
                }
                    break;
                case 'm': {
                    System.out.print("\n\tEnter name, ID, hours and pieces: ");
                }
                    break;
                } // switch
                workers[i].readFromInput(input);
            }

            workers[i].displaySalary();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question states that you have to store the references in a common array, where as you are storing them in 2 different arrays `a` and `b`. As you have different arrays for different type of objects, you don't have the need to use `instanceOf` operator. More about instanceOf is [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=332).

Also, you do not check for null while printing salary or bonus. As at any point of the loop, only one type of object will be created, one of a[i] or b[i] will be definitely null, causing a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

You need another loop after the one you have already written that will allow the user to input the worker's hours. This will presumably be a `while` loop that will continually ask for input. You would then choose some sort of input that would quit the loop. Inside the loop you ask for hours and take either 2 or 3 arguments.

At the moment you are not storing your Workers/MachineWorkers. You need to create an array to store them in. You also need to create either a base class or an interface that they will both extend/implement. This will allow you to create a single array to store them all.

You then loop through your array of Workers/MachineWorkers and when you find a matching id you use your `instanceof` to work out whether you need to pass 1 or 2 arguments. If it is a MachineWorker you should cast it as such and then call the appropriate method with 2 arguments.

Comment: In 'ID' why instanceof, I thought while comparing the array. I need to use instance of

Comment: You find the corresponding object with the appropriate id and then you use instanceof to know what to cast it to.